# apply function only within the same row index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 sorted indexes and I want to apply `diff` on the column only within `col1` in the order sorted by `col2`.

```
mini_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 'col2': [1,2,3,4],  'col3': [1,4,7,3]})
mini_df = mini_df.set_index(['col1', 'col2']).sort_index()
mini_df['diff'] = mini_df.col3.diff(1)
```

This gives me

```
              col3    diff
col1    col2  
__________________________
A        1      1      nan
         4      3       2
B        2      4       1
C        3      7       3
```

Above it applys `diff` by row.
What I want is

```
              col3    diff
col1    col2  
__________________________
A        1      1      nan
         4      3       2
B        2      4      nan
C        3      7      nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `groupby` to apply `diff` to each group:

```
mini_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 'col2': [1,2,3,4],  'col3': [1,4,7,3]})
mini_df = mini_df.set_index(['col1', 'col2']).sort_index()

mini_df['diff'] = mini_df.groupby(axis=0, level='col1')['col3'].diff()
```

Comment: Ammended..!! cheers, you can add that too, looks cleaner. :) Agreed on the minute point, however computing time should be lesser for bigger data

Comment: @anky_91 Yes it'll definitely save time with larger data. Shouldn't be ignored if that's the case. I'll update my post!

Answer (score 1):

Since you already go through the heavy lifting of `sort`, you can `diff` and only assign within the group. You can't `shift` non-datetime indices, so either make a `Series`, or use `np.roll`, though that wraps around, and would lead to the wrong answer for a single group `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(mini_df.index.get_level_values('col1'))
mini_df['diff'] = mini_df.col3.diff().where(s.eq(s.shift(1)).values)

           col3  diff
col1 col2            
A    1        1   NaN
     4        3   2.0
B    2        4   NaN
C    3        7   NaN
```